# PHPUnit - Error: Call to undefined function in Test file

Tags: php

I'm getting this error when I try to call a function before referencing another class the exists in the same file as the function I'm trying to call.

This error don't occur if the line `// new ICMS;` is uncommented.

Composer json

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Gbbs\\NfeCalculos\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Gbbs\\NfeCalculos\\Tests\\": "tests"
        }
    },
```

Folder structure

```
nfe-calculos/
├── src/
│  └── ICMS.php
└── tests/
   └── ICMSTest.php
```

ICMS.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Gbbs\NfeCalculos;

use Exception;

class ICMS
{}

function pICMSFromUFs(string $ufOrigem, string $ufDestino): float
{
    throw new Exception('UF inexistente: ' . $ufOrigem . ' - ' . $ufDestino);
}
```

ICMSTest.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Gbbs\NfeCalculos\Tests;

use Gbbs\NfeCalculos\ICMS;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

use function Gbbs\NfeCalculos\pICMSFromUFs;

class ICMSTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Test invalid UFs
     */
    public function testInvalidUFsInpICMSFromUFs()
    {
        // new ICMS;
        $this->expectException('\Exception');
        pICMSFromUFs('1', '1');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to call the function, then you will have to include the source file (`require_once()` or similar).

What is happening is that the autoloader is detecting you want to use the `ICMS` class and so it's loading the file for you.  This includes the function you are calling.

You could do something like add an `echo` in the ICMS.php source file and you should see this being displayed to prove this.

TBH - a source file should only really be the class, if the function is something to do with the class, you possibly could add it as a `static` method and call it as

```
ICMS::pICMSFromUFs('1', '1');
```